# Kue (node.js) job doesn't run on remote server but works in development env

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, redis, kue

I use https://github.com/Automattic/kue for creating jobs. Locally all works correctly. But when I run my application on remote server (Amazon, Ubuntu 18) the job is not run.

Here is my local config:

```
port 1234
daemonize yes
dbfilename data.rdb
notify-keyspace-events Ex
```

Initially, My thought was that this is config issue but when I grab server config (it's different with local one) and use it in local environment. Things still work.

When, I go to the remote server and run 2 redis clients there. Subscribe to channel in one, and publish test message in another (per https://redis.io/topics/notifications). This test also works fine. That means that keyspace notifications configured properly.

The last thought I have is that something in OS blocks it because on previous versions on Ubuntu that logic worked correctly (locally I use ffuenf/ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64 in vagrant) So, the question is: are there anything in OS that can block Redis Keyspace Notifications?